# Xcode unable to fetch pods lib path

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

i have fetched a code via git. it already has a pod setup.  i am unable to compile the code since all the libs in pods prodect are listed red, i have read a few a forums and i do have the latest cocoa pods + opening the workspace file not the xcodeproj. the issue seems to be Xcode unable to reference agains those libs , any help ?

i have tried using $inherited in the header paths but nothing works . the error is

```
ld: library not found for -lOCMock
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: show the content of podfile, and did you run 'pod update' command, before trying to open xcodeproj

Comment: no i didn't , i cloned the repo , removed the workspace file that came with it and created pod setup , pod install .

Comment: solved it , i just had to re-reference the lib , removed it and added the reference again

Comment: You need to add $(inherited) to the LIBRARY SEARCH PATH, as well as to header search path